# Question about "place of business" in trade license/business license [Bangladesh]

Tags: business, business-lease, bangladesh

My brother wants to start a software business. So, he got a [trade license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_license) form. In there, there is a field with the name "place of business". If the place of business is rented, then a copy of the document/deed of the [rental agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rental_agreement) has to be provided as well.

Now, my brother intends to rent a place and provide the corresponding deed (rental agreement) and address of that place. However, the problem is that he won't work from there. As it is a software business, he will do nearly all, if not all of his work, from home. So, there is a sizable possibility that he won't go there for work more than once per year.

For technical difficulties, he can't put our home address as the place of business.

So, even though he won't work at that place, is it legal to provide that place as the place of business?

PS: Even if you aren't well versed in the laws of Bangladesh, explaining this situation from the legal perspective of your country will also be appreciated, as there should be commonality among the laws.

Comment: Is your brother starting a one-man shop? What is the purpose of the rental, just this form, or are their business reasons as well (meeting clients, storing documents, storing servers, office for other works, be they devs, salespeople, business analysts, etc.)

Comment: Will the business be registered as a private limited company or sole proprietorship?

Comment: @Rick sole proprietorship

Comment: @Sharur He's starting a sole proprietorship (one-man-shop). He's renting the place just to fill out the form.

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic: to clarify (at least in English), "sole proprietorship" and "one man-shop" are separate ideas completely ("sole proprietorship" describes the ownership structure, being directly owned a single individual; "one-man-shop" describes a business where the owner is the only worker; in essence there are no employees or contractors).

Comment: @sharur Yes, I understand the difference now. Currently it is a one-man-shop **and** a sole proprietorship.